# Xcache not refreshing the files when deploying with webistrano/capistrano

Tags: php, capistrano, web-deployment, symlink, xcache

I am deploying my code using webistrano. A new release is created as well as the doc root symlink works fine, but when I try to access my website on browser , still the old code is referenced. This issue is because somehow xcache is not updating its cache. When I manually touch all the files of the code , then it works fine.

Please let me know what could be the issue or how xcache handles the files path internally which might be causing this issue.

I found that if I manually clean xcache from xcache-admin then it start working fine, but is there any way that I can clear xcache in one-go from php file or shell command.

Thanks!!

Comment: can u show your xcache configuration

Comment: I have all default configuration. I found that clearing xcache solve the issue, but is there any way to clear that using php or shell command.

Comment: Although I was able to write a script to clear xcache in php, but even that doesn't solve the issue. Finally we are doing apache restart every time we deploy.

Comment: Are you using PHP-FPM or mod_fcgi? It could be the realpath cache for the individual processes not getting cleared.